# CSS: How to flip this linear-gradient?

Tags: html, css

I have this code which creates a line of triangles. It's quite nice, but I want it inverse. Instead the edges to be up, to be down. I tried like for 30 minutes to make it work... I just don't get the linear-gradient.
Here is the current output
[image]

And I want it to be like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #E4E1D6 25%, transparent 25%,transparent), 
                  linear-gradient(-45deg, #E4E1D6 25%, transparent 25%, transparent), 
                  linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #E4E1D6 75%),                
                  linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #E4E1D6 75%);
  width: 100%;
  background-position: 0px 7px;
  position: relative;
  top: -47px;
  height: 7px;
  background-size: 10px 12px;
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

Simply change `background-position: 0px 7px` to `background-position: 0 0`

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #E4E1D6 25%, transparent 25%,transparent), 
                  linear-gradient(-45deg, #E4E1D6 25%, transparent 25%, transparent), 
                  linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #E4E1D6 75%),                
                  linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #E4E1D6 75%);
  width: 100%;
  background-position: 0 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 7px;
  background-size: 10px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```